# How to use Omniauth + capybara for testing FB Connect?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, capybara, omniauth

I have a rails 3 app + devise using capybara for integration tests. Right now I have sign and sign up tests working but don't have tests for FB Connect.

How can I add Omniauth tests to ensure sign up and sign in work? Any one have an example or a up to date tutorial that shows how this is done? All I could find is fragments of info.

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for something like https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/Integration-Testing

Comment: Thanks yes I've been reading that but that doesn't show an end to end example so I haven't been able to get it working

Answer (score 4):

I don't have the complete example. I added the following to my test.rb(You can add it to a initializer and add it if the enviroment is test).

```
  OmniAuth.config.test_mode = true

  FACEBOOK_INFO = {
    "id"=> "220439",
    "email" => "bret@facebook.com",
  }

  OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:facebook] = {
    "uid" => '12345',
    "provider" => 'facebook',
    "user_info" => {"name" => "Bret Taylor", "nickname" => 'btaylor'},
    "credentials" => {"token" => 'plataformatec'},
    "extra" => {"user_hash" => FACEBOOK_INFO}
  }
```

This simulates the call to omniauth. So in your test, when you simulate a click to the facebook button, the response you will get is the one from OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:facebook].

Comment: Thanks, I added that to my spec_helper.rb

Comment: What does the "id" corresponds to? Where do we find the actual credential token? Thanks

Comment: You get the credential token via a call to a facebook dialog. If you want a webpage that helps you retrieve the credential token, I use the code from this repo https://github.com/innku/authorizefb